# "temporal scope" is to time as X is to area?

Tags: phrase-request

A statement which is temporally scoped implies that the statement stands only in that timepoint or between that time interval.

What should I use if I want to express that the statement holds only in a particular or some areas or countries? For instance, [these terms](https://www.mondly.com/blog/2020/05/14/87-australian-slang-terms-speak-aussie/) are only idiomatic in Australia and hence X scoped. Is "geometry scope" idiomatic (in whatever English speaking country)?

Comment: It would make more sense to use "geographically scoped" than "geometrically scoped".

Comment: Or possibly **regionally scoped**.

Comment: Peter's answer isn't everyday idiomatic English, but it's *just as idiomatic* as "temporally scoped". So "geographically scoped" is the right answer in any context where you can also use "temporally scoped", which I'm imagining is some academic context.

Answer (score 1):

Spatial would be a good fit.

References:

1. https://edepot.wur.nl/194230
2. https://www.ida.liu.se/ext/brs/scope/str/index.html